# Improve a fraction's appearance

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Omega(E)=\dfrac{ N!}{\left(\dfrac{N}{2}-\dfrac{E}{2\mu H}\right)!\left(\dfrac{N}{2}+\dfrac{E}{2\mu H}\right)!}\,\dfrac{\delta E}{2\mu H}
\label{eq:OmegaFinal}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

What I would like to have is the `2μΗ` to be better aligned to the left denominator. Secondly the factorial, would be better if it was longer.

Comment: @lpsen: Thank you very much for your comment! If you notice, the `2μΗ` it isn't well aligned with the left denominator. Secondly the factorial, would be better if it was longer, I believe.

Comment: I don't like to use `\dfrac`. My suggestion is to remove them from the denominator. Or, what do you think: `\Omega(E)=\frac{N!}{\left(N/{2}-E/{(2\mu H)}\right)!\left(N/{2}+E/{(2\mu H)}\right)!}\,\frac{\delta E}{2\mu H}`

Comment: @Sigur: Thank you for your comment! The picture that I gave actually is without `\dfrac` on the denominator. As far as your suggestion is concerned, I would like to have it in a fraction and not with just a slash.

Comment: The first `\dfrac` is not necessary since you are using `equation`. I told you to remove from denominator based on your example code. Now, looking the picture I could notice that `N`is smaller on denominator. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick. Not so fancy but it works. Probably some one could help you with a fancy command.

```
\Omega(E)=\frac{ N!}{\left(\frac{N}{2}-\frac{E}{2\mu H}\right)!\left(\frac{N}{2}+\frac{E}{2\mu H}\right)!}\,\frac{\delta E}{2\mu H \hspace{-1.5em}\phantom{\left(\frac{E}{\mu}\right.}}
```

I inserted a `\phantom` command to fake the denominator.

[image]

Here is another suggestion: replace `\left( \right)` by `\big( \big)`and change the order of the fractions, as @percusse said.

```
\Omega(E)=\frac{\delta E}{2\mu H \hspace{-1.5em}\phantom{\left(\frac{E}{\mu}\right.}} \frac{ N!}{\big(\frac{N}{2}-\frac{E}{2\mu H}\big)!\big(\frac{N}{2}+\frac{E}{2\mu H}\big)!}
```

[image]

Comment: It is really better! Thank you very much! Any idea on the `!` apart from changing fontsize? I mean something like `\left` and `\right`...

Comment: @Thanos Oh please don't do that :P I mean if they are factorials don't touch them. However you might consider having `2muH` to the left but under the frac while putting `\delta E` outside as a factor. That might bring some balance to the eye.

Comment: @percusse: That could be an idea but I want it in that form because it is a term which indicate something specific, so it should stay like that. About the `!`, I'll leave it like that! You convinced me!

Comment: Use `\vphantom{<stuff>}` instead of a combination of `\phantom` and a manual negative horizontal space. (There’s also `\hphantom` for only a horizontal space the size of its argument.) Also, use `\big(` in the second suggestion’s `\phantom`, this would correct the vertical alignment again.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose for the 1st fraction, to use the \mfrac command (= medium sized fraction) from the nccmath package and the \cfrac command, plus thickspace (\;) between the two factorials at the denominator :

`\Omega(E)=\mfrac{ N!}{\Bigl(\cfrac{N}{2}-\cfrac{E}{2\mu H}\Bigr)!\;\Bigl(\cfrac{N}{2}+\cfrac{E}{2\mu H}\Bigr)!}\,\dfrac{\delta E}{2\mu H}`